# How do you say "continue doing"?

Tags: translation

How do you say in Esperanto *continue doing*?

For example:

*He continued living there for the rest of his life.*

Answer (score 10):

There are different ways to express this concept in Esperanto.

In the case of actions, you can use the word *[plu](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/e-vortecaj_vortetoj/tempaj/plu.html)* 'further, more' as a prefix to the verb:

> Ili pluiris 'They went on'
>
> Ili plulaboros 'They'll continue working'

In the case states like in your example this is possible, too, but you can also add the adverb *daŭre* 'continuously', or, if there is no reason to emphasize the continuity, leave it to the context:

> Li (daŭre) vivis tie ĝis la fino de sia vivo

For stylistic reasons this seems a bit better to me than *pluvivis*.

Comment: Ĉu vi celis diri tion ĉi?:

_Li (daŭre) **loĝis** tie ĝis la fino de sia vivo._

(Redaktita por akcentigi la vorton, kiun mi korektis)

Answer (score 5):

Some other forms: `daŭrigi` as help verb (similar to the English scheme), and `plue` as accented `plu`.

> Li daŭrigis loĝi tie dum la resto de sia vivo
>
> Li loĝis tie plue dum la resto de sia vivo

(I changed `daŭris` to `daŭrigis` - one is never too old to make mistakes.)

Comment: Even though I found some instances of *daŭri …i* in Tekstaro, it is mentioned that this is not proper usage: «oni povas diri: “la laboro daŭras” […], sed oni ne povas diri: “mi daŭras labori” […].» from Lingvaj Respondoj, Respondo 49, Oficiala Gazeto, 1911, p. 294. Note that in the same paragraph Zamenhof claims that *daŭrigi …i* is wrong, however PMEG deems the use of *daŭrigi …i* to be good, as most seem to. ([Source](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/gravaj_verboj/komenci_fini_daurigi_chesi.html#i-29j).) PMEG does agree that *daŭri …i* is incorrect.

Comment: @Joffysloffy You are right that `tio daŭras` and `mi daŭras labori` have a different sense for _daŭras_. The verb _kontinui_ or _resti_ as help verb are very rare too and have the same issue, and probably many will find those usages wrong. `Li restas loĝanta`? `pluloĝi` is without problem, but is so bloodless.

Comment: You're plainly using *daŭri* in the sense of *daŭrigi*, as suggested by PMEG. I don't see a reason for *daŭri …i* to exist when *daŭrigi …i* has the intended meaning and is more logically constructed, as PMEG suggests: *Mi daŭrigas labori* ≈ *Mi daŭrigas mian laboron*. The fact that it is asymmetrical w.r.t. *ĉesi* is just unfortunate, but it is the way it is. I don't understand what issue you have with the word *pluloĝi* and whatever ‘bloodless’ means in this context. Also *Li restas loĝanta* seems perfectly fine, because here *resti* expresses the retainment of a state.

Comment: @Joffysloffy Thanks. It seems I did not understand your first comment. I stand corrected.

Comment: @JoopEgen Ah, excellent. Consequently my downvote has become an upvote :). You might still want to change *daŭri* to *daŭrigi* in the first line of your answer though!

Comment: I was thinking of including _daŭrigi_ into my answer, too, but refrained, because for me _li daŭrigis loĝi_ is ambiguous. It can IMHO also mean that he stopped living there for a while and now started living there again. But I didn't enterprise a corpus search in order to check whether my gut feeling is right...

Comment: @CyrilRobertBrosch Like "he resumed living there". I think _daŭrigi_ is clean enough. Ethymologically the word comes from _duration_ for instance.

Answer (score 1):

There's already a couple of suggestions involving plu: as a prefix or as *plue*. Just don't forget that you can use good old *plu* in its natural form too:

Li **vivis plu** tie ĝis la fino de sia vivo.
Li **plu vivis** tie ĝis la fino de sia vivo.

It might be a little weird in that *plu* is not a verb like “continue”, but it conveys the same meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a fairy tale ending to me. [Here's](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cindrulino)

*Ili geedziĝas kaj vivas feliĉe ĉiam.*

so *vivas ĉiam* is a possible translation.